# SFML Drawing centered text

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to center some text in SFML. It doesen't really work though as you can see in the picture below.
[image]

Maybe something is wrong with my math?

```
void TextRenderer::renderCentered(sf::RenderWindow& window, std::string string, sf::Vector2f     position, int size, sf::Color color) {
    sf::Text text;

    text.setFont(TextRenderer::kavoon);
    text.setString(string);

    float width = text.getLocalBounds().width;

    text.setPosition(position.x - width / 2, position.y);

    text.setCharacterSize(size);
    text.setColor(color);

    window.draw(text);
}
```

in render method:

```
TextRenderer::renderCentered(*window, pickuptext.str(), sf::Vector2f(player->sprite.getPosition().x, player->sprite.getPosition().y - 48), 28, sf::Color(255, 145, 61));
TextRenderer::renderCentered(*window, pickuptextdesc.str(), sf::Vector2f(player->sprite.getPosition().x, player->sprite.getPosition().y - 16), 18, sf::Color(255, 145, 61));
```

Comment: Is `position.x` the center or left position of the bounding box?

Comment: Not sure if you'll run into this, but I've noticed that certain fonts, probably one's with improper glyph sizes, don't play nicely with SFML's bounding functions (they end up with excess padding, so to speak). For now hard-coded adjustments seem to be the only way to deal with this. The changelog for SFML 2.2 includes an `Info` struct for each `sf::Font` which may be helpful later on, but currently only details the font's family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for centering text horizontally within a bounding box is:

```
text_start = bounding_box_width / 2 - text_width / 2;
```

Looks like you may not be supplying the bounding box horizontal center point.

Comment: How do I account for the player position? What is the bounding box,  the players bounding box?

Comment: The bounding box is the bounding box or rectangle for the text.

Comment: So what's text_width? Isn't it the same?

Comment: In SFML text_width would be `text.getGlobalBounds().width`. Essentially Thomas Matthews' formula would be `text.setPositon(sf::Vector2f(position.x / 2 - text.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, position.y));`

Comment: Sorry, that should read `text.setPositon(sf::Vector2f(position.x - text.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, position.y));`