# Centering text on top of buttons in SFML

Tags: c++, windows, sfml, clion

I have been trying to find a formula for centering text but I cannot get it to work on text of all lengths so I am kind of stuck and can't figure out a way to properly center everything. Here's what I have so far:

```
void Button::set_pos(sf::Vector2f pos) {
    button.setPosition(pos);

    float pos_x = (pos.x + button.getLocalBounds().width/3.0f) -
                  (text.getGlobalBounds().width/2);
    float pos_y = (pos.y + button.getLocalBounds().height/3.0f) -
                  (text.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
    text.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
}
```

this however doesn't work for all lengths of text as you can see
[image]

How can i get this to center properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SFML Drawing centered text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806077/sfml-drawing-centered-text)

Comment: It unfortunately does not, I've tried it before and it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Then I have one question: Do you set the string of the text (`sf::Text::setString`) before calling `set_pos`? Because if so, there is your problem. You must call `set_pos` when the string is already set. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense and you are either skipping important information or have not tried correctly the solution of the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Text in sfml start at lower left corner instead of up left. i use `text.getLocalBounds()` instead of `text.getGlobalBounds()`. Works for me. Had the same problem.

Plus make sure the text is not empty. ie use `text.setString()` before any transformations.

https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9834.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getGlobalBounds()` with button instead of `.getLocalBounds()`. That should work.

```cpp
void Button::set_pos(sf::Vector2f pos) {
    button.setPosition(pos);

    float pos_x = (pos.x + button.getGlobalBounds().width/3.0f) -
                  (text.getGlobalBounds().width/2);
    float pos_y = (pos.y + button.getGlobalBounds().height/3.0f) -
                  (text.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
    text.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
}
```